# looking for macro which will replace function

Tags: c++, c, macros, legacy, side-effects

I dont know if name of topic exactly introduces my problem, but thing is:
in my company code, there is a function, for example:

```
float func_x(float a){
      float b
      return b
}
```

that function occuers in about 1000 places. Now the new function has been added:

```
void func_x2(void *a, void *b){
     do sth
}
```

This function should replace all occuerences of `func_x` in code, so change should happen from (pseudocode):

```
float p = 123.33;
float x = func_x(p) 
to:
float x;
float p = 123.33;
func_x2((void *)&p, (void*)&x);
```

My question is:
Is it **even possible** to write some C macro (even very sophisticated) which will replace func_x into func_x2, so the code will not change at all ? Anyone tried to do it ?

regards
J

Comment: This is bad practice because it makes the code basically unreadable. You can't believe any function call you read because maybe a macro changes it. You can never trust what you read. Your source code becomes a lie.

Comment: Thank God I don't work for your company. Just remove the original function and manually fix the 1000 places it is called. 1000 places isn't so many. It's a one time job and the code will be left in a much better state than if you used some macro hackery. In the past I've had to maintain code like this, it's is a nightmare.

Comment: It may be possible, but it certainly not the best practice. The time 'saved' doing this will be lost 10 times over maintaining it.

Comment: By the way, it's funny how your company wants to replace 1,000 readable, already working and type-safe function calls by one with the signature "void func_x2(void *a, void *b)".

Comment: I truly hope that the `func_x2` declaration and usage does not even remotely look like that abomination you showed here. But otoh it fits that you are trying to bulldoze over the last remaining shreds of maintainability with a macro.

Comment: `func_x2((void *)&p, (void*)&x);` get rid of the casts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not just replacing the function's implementation but also it's signature. Any macro declaring the extra variable will surely lead to errors because you cannot declare variables at every site where you can call functions.

The best way is to use your editor's find and replace function, fixing this case-by-case.

Comment: Easiest example: `float x = func_x(1.0f) + func_x(2.0f);`

Answer (score 4):

I have no idea of the what the functions really do, but in case x2 is just a extension of x, you could do something like that

```
float func_x(float a){
  float b;
  func_x2((void *)&a, (void *)&b);
  return b;
}
```

Comment: Agree with this. I'm assuming that `func_x2` is some ancient, field-proven code, because anything else wouldn't justify that horrible interface. And the proper way to deal with such an old beast is to wrap in in the correct typesafe interface, like this.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what you want isn't possible. You could though rename/remove the original func_x and replace it with a function which just calls func_x2.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to use a regual expression to replace all occurences of the old function.

This regexp catches the example given in the question

```
^.*?\s(.*)\s*=\s*func_x\(\s*(.*)\)
```

and then you can use something like this to replace it with

```
float \2;\nfunc_x2\(\(void \*\)&\2, \(void\*\)&\1\)
```

Of course you would probably have to tweak this regexp a bit and there are different flavors of regular expressions but it gives you an idea of what you could do.

Comment: that is a bad idea, because the function has side effects and you need to make sure that you are introducing the new variables in the right place.

Comment: I do think that it should be possible to create a regular expression that makes a change equivalent to what's in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible since you're trying to modify the function definition and implementation as well.!